# Big CSV files processing suggestion on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata

Need some suggestion on services that I can use on AWS for the following case.

A bucket receives around 60 gzipped CSV files everyday. All of them are max size which is 5GB. A row in a CSV is an piece of order information like below:

```
order_id, customer_id, item_id, payment_method, amount
1,        1,           1,       cash,           10.00
1,        1,           2,       cash,           11.00
2,        1,           1,       credit,         12.00
3,        2,           3,       cash,           13.00
3,        2,           4,       cash,           14.00
3,        2,           5,       credit,         15.00
```

**A customer's orders could be distributed in every gzipped file without sorting**, I'm working on a system that could aggregate **ALL** orders of a customer in the 60 files into an Customer instance defined like below:

```
class Customer {
    private String customerId;
    private Set<Order> orders;
}

class Order {
    private String orderId;
    private Set<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    private String itemId;
    private String paymentMethod;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

Eventually I will get 2 customer instances with id 1 and 2 having their order and item information inside it and send the 2 customer instances to another service for further processing.

Currently, I'm thinking using several ECS tasks to read each of the files and inserting a CSV row into DynamoDB as an object with customerId defined as index. Once all files are processed, I can start some other ECS tasks to read from DynamoDB by indexed customerId so I can do the aggregation.

Just want to check if there is any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Amazon Athena.** It can run SQL against files stored in Amazon S3, including CSV files.

It is most efficient when the files are in a **columnar format** like Parquet and ORC, but CSV is fine. It can even read them in **gzip format**, which also reduces cost because Athena pricing is based upon the amount of data read from disk.

Athena will **read across all files stored under a given directory**, so it would be relatively simple to select data from a particular customer, or to sort all data in by customer, order, item, etc.

You can point an **AWS Glue crawler** to at the data and it can automatically determine the format and fields, creating a table definition. You can then simply run the SQL in Athena. No programming required!

Answer (score 0):

How about using AWS data pipeline to ingest data to dynomodb from the S3.

What you can do is to trigger data pipeline on object received to the S3 ( you can do it with a lambda function triggering to S3 put event )

Try this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

This will remove your ECS cluster for data ingesstion.

But to process the data you may use the ECS cluster.

Comment: From what I tested, I think data pipeline can't process gzip format CSV.

Comment: I think you are correct, we need to perform an extra step in the lamda function to extract the compressed file and import to the dynomoDB. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: Hi just wonder if you have any CSV sample that works on data pipeline. With a normal CSV, I still don't make it work. Have to convert it into the exported from DDB format.